# How can I extract start and end codon from DNA sequences in Perl?

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

I have a code below that try to identify the position of start and end codon of the given DNA sequences.
We define *start codon as* a **ATG** sequence and *end codon* as **TGA,TAA,TAG** sequences.

The problem I have is that the code below works only for first two sequences (DM208659 and AF038953) but not the rest.

What's wrong with my approach below?

This code can be copy-pasted from [here](http://dpaste.com/106467/plain/).

```
      #!/usr/bin/perl -w


while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    print "$_\n";
    my ($id,$rna_sq) = split(/\s+/,$_);

    local $_ = $rna_sq;
    while (/atg/g) {
        my $start = pos() - 2;

        if (/tga|taa|tag/g) {

            my $stop    = pos();
            my $gene    = substr( $_, $start - 1, $stop - $start + 1 ),$/;
            my $genelen = length($gene);
            my $ct      = "$id $start $stop $gene $genelen";
            print "\t$ct\n";

        }

    }

}

__DATA__
DM208659    gtgggcctcaaatgtggagcactattctgatgtccaagtggaaagtgctgcgacatttgagcgtcac
AF038953    gatcccagacctcggcttgcagtagtgttagactgaagataaagtaagtgctgtttgggctaacaggatctcctcttgcagtctgcagcccaggacgctgattccagcagcgccttaccgcgcagcccgaagattcactatggtgaaaatcgccttcaatacccctaccgccgtgcaaaaggaggaggcgcggcaagacgtggaggccctcctgagccgcacggtcagaactcagatactgaccggcaaggagctccgagttgccacccaggaaaaagagggctcctctgggagatgtatgcttactctcttaggcctttcattcatcttggcaggacttattgttggtggagcctgcatttacaagtacttcatgcccaagagcaccatttaccgtggagagatgtgcttttttgattctgaggatcctgcaaattcccttcgtggaggagagcctaacttcctgcctgtgactgaggaggctgacattcgtgaggatgacaacattgcaatcattgatgtgcctgtccccagtttctctgatagtgaccctgcagcaattattcatgactttgaaaagggaatgactgcttacctggacttgttgctggggaactgctatctgatgcccctcaatacttctattgttatgcctccaaaaaatctggtagagctctttggcaaactggcgagtggcagatatctgcctcaaacttatgtggttcgagaagacctagttgctgtggaggaaattcgtgatgttagtaaccttggcatctttatttaccaactttgcaataacagaaagtccttccgccttcgtcgcagagacctcttgctgggtttcaacaaacgtgccattgataaatgctggaagattagacacttccccaacgaatttattgttgagaccaagatctgtcaagagtaagaggcaacagatagagtgtccttggtaataagaagtcagagatttacaatatgactttaacattaaggtttatgggatactcaagatatttactcatgcatttactctattgcttatgccgtaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
BC021011    ggggagtccggggcggcgcctggaggcggagccgcccgctgggctaaatggggcagaggccgggaggggtgggggttccccgcgccgcagccatggagcagcttcgcgccgccgcccgtctgcagattgttctg
DM208660    gggatactcaaaatgggggcgctttcctttttgtctgtactgggaagtgcttcgattttggggtgtccc
AF038954    ggacccaagggggccttcgaggtgccttaggccgcttgccttgctctcagaatcgctgccgccatggctagtcagtctcaggggattcagcagctgctgcaggccgagaagcgggcagccgagaaggtgtccgaggcccgcaaaagaaagaaccggaggctgaagcaggccaaagaagaagctcaggctgaaattgaacagtaccgcctgcagagggagaaagaattcaaggccaaggaagctgcggcattgggatcccgtggcagttgcagcactgaagtggagaaggagacccaggagaagatgaccatcctccagacatacttccggcagaacagggatgaagtcttggacaacctcttggcttttgtctgtgacattcggccagaaatccatgaaaactaccgcataaatggatagaagagagaagcacctgtgctgtggagtggcattttagatgccctcacgaatatggaagcttagcacagctctagttacattcttaggagatggccattaaattatttccatatattataagagaggtccttccactttttggagagtagccaatctagctttttggtaacagacttagaaattagcaaagatgtccagctttttaccacagattcctgagggattttagatgggtaaatagagtcagactttgaccaggttttgggcaaagcacatgtatatcagtgtggacttttcctttcttagatctagtttaaaaaaaaaaaccccttaccattctttgaagaaaggaggggattaaataattttttcccctaacactttcttgaaggtcaggggctttatctatgaaaagttagtaaatagttctttgtaacctgtgtgaagcagcagccagccttaaagtagtccattcttgctaatggttagaacagtgaatactagtggaattgtttgggctgcttttagtttctcttaatcaaaattactagatgatagaattcaagaacttgttacatgtattacttggtgtatcgataatcatttaaaagtaaagactctgtcatgcaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: Regarding biology: I presume you do realise that a TGA in a result like "AF038953 140 146 atggtga 7" is not a valid stop codon because it's out of frame? Also, to be picky, it's not an RNA sequence, as $rna_sq would imply.

Comment: @PhiS: very good point; if frames were to be considered properly, then perhaps one could split up the sequence into three-letter chunks with split, and then parse through that iteratively.

Comment: I hope for you that this is just an exercise. There are a lot of libraries for doing this already available and tested, consider using them if you want your results to be reproducible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed the use of `$_` (I especially shuddered when you `local`ized it -- you did so correctly, but why force yourself to worry if some other function is going to clobber `$_`, rather than use `$rna_sq` which is already available?

Additionally I corrected `$start` and `$stop` to be 0-based indexes into the string (which made the rest of the math more straight-forward), and calculated `$genelen` early so it could be used directly in the `substr` operation.  (Alternatively, you could localize `$[` to 1 to use 1-based array indexes, see [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;
    print "processing $line\n";
    my ($id, $rna_sq) = split(/\s+/, $line);

    while ($rna_sq =~ /atg/g) {
        # $start and $stop are 0-based indexes
        my $start = pos($rna_sq) - 3; # back up to include the start sequence

        # discard remnant if no stop sequence can be found
        last unless $rna_sq =~ /tga|taa|tag/g;

        my $stop    = pos($rna_sq);
        my $genelen = $stop - $start;

        my $gene    = substr($rna_sq, $start, $genelen);
        print "\t" . join(' ', $id, $start+1, $stop, $gene, $genelen) . "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's never breaking out of your inner loop when the `if (/tga|taa|tag/g)` fails to find an end codon. It keeps matching `/atg/g` repeatedly, never advancing any further. You could forcibly eject it from the inner loop:

```
if (/tga|taa|tag/g) {
    ...
}
else {
    last;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on whether you want to generate sequences which could overlap. For example, sequence AF038954 contains `atgaccatcctccagacatacttccggcagaacagggatga`, the end of which overlaps with `atgaagtcttggacaacctcttggcttttgtctgtga`. Do you want to report them both?

If you don't want to report sequences which overlap, this is a very simple problem, which you can solve with a single regexp:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    print "processing $_\n";
    my ($id, $rna_sq) = split;

    while ($rna_sq =~ /(atg.*?(?:tga|taa|tag))/g) {
      printf "\t%8s %4i %4i %s %i\n",
             $id,
             pos($rna_sq) - length($1) + 1,
             pos($rna_sq),
             $1,
             length($1);
      }
}
```

The regexp `(atg.*?(?:tga|taa|tag))` matches your required start, then as little as possible of what comes next (that's the `?` to stop the `.*` being "greedy") then your required end. Iterating over it with the `while` loop restarts *after* this match, which meets the requirement of not looking for overlaps.

If you *do* want overlapping sequences reported, you do need a two-stage process: find the start, find the end, and then find another start, picking up where you left off looking for the start the last time. But you can still do a simpler job using a second regexp:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    print "processing $_\n";
    my ($id, $rna_sq) = split;

    while ($rna_sq =~ /atg/g) {
      if ($' =~ /(.*?(?:tga|taa|tag))/) {
        my $match = "atg$1";
        printf "\t%8s %4i %4i %s %i\n",
               $id,
               pos($rna_sq) - 2,
               pos($rna_sq) - 3 + length($match),
               $match,
               length($match);
      }
    }
}
```

Here we use the (generally non-recommended) `$'` special variable, which contains the content after the match. We look in this to find the end of the sequence and output the details. Because our main global match against `$rna_seq` doesn't include the sequence (as it does above) we restart the search for a start where the previous search left off, that is just after the start we found. This way we *do* include overlapping sequences.